# Restarting kernel for one and only one .ipynb document in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

I have a process running in one of .ipynb document in jupyter for many hours using Python3 kernel. I don't need it to die. I was working in the other document in parallel using the same Python3 kernel and the process got stuck.

I wonder if I can restart kernel for one document only? Or at least to stop the process for this document. Interrupt the kernel button doesn't work.

Comment: What's a Python3 kernel? Are you referring to interpreter? Because a Kernel is what makes the Linux operating system just that, the OS itself.

Comment: It's called kernel in jupyter notebooks

Comment: Ok, I changed the tag

Comment: \*curses vigilantly about people messing up naming conventions*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter typically starts a new kernel for each notebook you open. So even if you have two Python 3 notebooks running, the kernels are not the same.